# Copy folder on publish ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, msbuild, csproj

I need to copy the Views folder to the publish folder (on publish),
and I have this in my `.csproj`.

(*Note: I don't need to change the views on runtime, different usage*)

```
<Target Name="CopyViews" BeforeTargets="Build;Publish">
    <ItemGroup>
        <ViewsFiles Include="Views\**\*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(ViewsFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)\Views" />
</Target>
```

This works for build, the `Views` gets copied to the `bin` folder,
but when I publish it doesn't get copied in the publish folder.

Comment: Normally `$(OutDir)` is the same for `build` and `publish` and is the `bin` folder, not the publish folder. If your project is an SDK style project you can include `@(ViewsFiles)` in `@(None)` and set metadata of  `CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest"` and  `CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" `. (`CopyToOutputDirectory` is supported in legacy style projects. Not sure about `CopyToPublishDirectory`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try configure them separately:

```
    <Target Name="CopyViews_build" BeforeTargets="Build">
        <ItemGroup>
            <ViewsFiles Include="Views\**\*" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(ViewsFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(OutDir)\Views" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="CopyViews_publish" BeforeTargets="Publish">
        <ItemGroup>
            <ViewsFiles Include="Views\**\*" />
        </ItemGroup>
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(ViewsFiles)" DestinationFolder="$(PublishDir)\Views" />
    </Target>
```

Publish Test
[image]

Comment: Thanx, you did answer my question, just noticed now that the folder structure is not copied as is (seems because of `\**\*`) , but that's a different problem.